# How to use Filter on a aggregated column in a calculated table Power BI

Tags: group-by, powerbi, dax

I have source table, and I have created another calculated table from the source table to group by Hours column with pay period, full name, and attendance type. Now I want to create a measure that filters out the grouped hours by attendance type 'Regular' hour and another measure for leaves with attendance type Annual, Sick, Family Sick. But I am not able to do it using filter function. Below codes I have tried but giving me odd numbers. I want to do simple filter of my grouped hours by attendance types.

In SQL: select GroupedHours from GroupedTable where Attendance type ="Regular"

Is there any other way I can achieve the expected result? Can any one help me on this?

```
HoursWorked = (CALCULATE(SUM(Budget_Attendance_Report\[HOURS\]),TableGroupByPP\[Budget_Attendance_Report_ATTENDANCE_TYPE\]="Rrgular"))

TotalLeave2 = CALCULATE(SUM(TableGroupByPP\[TotalGrpHrsPP\]),TableGroupByPP\[Budget_Attendance_Report_ATTENDANCE_TYPE\] ="Annual" || "Sick" || "FamilySick")
```

Answer (score 0):

In the first measure, `Regular` is misspelt.  In the second measure, you can use `IN` syntax to get the other attendance types.

If these do not work, please update the question with expected vs actual results.  Sample data would be helpful in that case as well.

```
HoursWorked =
(
    CALCULATE (
        SUM ( Budget_Attendance_Report[HOURS] ),
        TableGroupByPP[Budget_Attendance_Report_ATTENDANCE_TYPE] = "Regular"
    )
)


TotalLeave2 =
CALCULATE (
    SUM ( TableGroupByPP[TotalGrpHrsPP] ),
    TableGroupByPP[Budget_Attendance_Report_ATTENDANCE_TYPE]
        IN { "Annual", "Sick", "FamilySick" }
)
```